# Javascript press an input once when HTML loaded and never again

Tags: javascript, python

so I am using a jQuery Ajax updater which uses jinja2 to determine values when a certain value is too I'm attempting to press an input which loads a url linked to flask. However I only want to go to this url once which is an issue as my updater refreshes every 0.5 seconds causing the link to be loaded multiple times.
Snippet of my updater with javascript to press button:

```
{% elif item['status'] == "pass" and item['api'] == "Yes" %}
        <td style="color: #DAA520;">Good</td>
        <input onclick="location.href = '/api';" type="hidden" id="popupbtn">
        <script>
            setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("popupbtn").click();}, 500);
        </script>
```

This is called every 0.5 seconds in index.html, I only want to press popupbtn once how can I achieve this? I was thinking I could just wait for the element to be visible in index.html and press it then, but how can I do that?

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense. You have a setTimeout, which runs a function every 500ms. The *ONLY* thing that's being done in that function is clicking an input. But then you say you only want that to happen once... So - Just don't use setTimeout. Are you leaving out other code? If so, please add it.

Comment: @TJBlackman I have lots of other code that I can't share basically I'm using jQuery Ajax to call the above code every 0.5 seconds

Comment: So just set a variable somewhere, and check it before clicking the input. `var wasClicked = false; setTimeout(function(){ if (wasClicked === false){ input.click(); wasClicked = true;} }, 500);`

Comment: If I remove the Timeout it's still called multiple times

Comment: @TJBlackman that will just says wasClicked to false everytime the html is reran though?

Comment: Yeah, it still just resets wasClicked to false everytime

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yafd4p6t/1/

Comment: @TJBlackman this is just using the snippet you already gave?

Comment: I see. The page is refreshing. So, you need to still use a variable as a flag somewhere, so use localStorage or a cookie to persist the state so you can decide whether or not to click the input. But other than that, the idea is the same

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use localStorage to maintain a status of the page and prevent the redirect on future clicks. In this example, "onclick" is removed from the input element and an event listener checks a stored variable to determine whether or not the redirect happens.

```
{% elif item['status'] == "pass" and item['api'] == "Yes" %}
        <td style="color: #DAA520;">Good</td>
        <input type="hidden" id="popupbtn">
        <script>

            // determine the status of the page
            function getPageStatus() {
                var pageStatus = 'initial';
                if (!(Storage===undefined)) {
                    if (!(pageStatus===undefined)) {
                        pageStatus = localStorage.pageStatus
                    } else {
                        localStorage.pageStatus = 'initial';
                    }
                }
                return pageStatus;
            }

            // set the status of the page
            function setPageStatus(newStatus) {
                if (!(Storage===undefined)) {
                    localStorage.pageStatus = newStatus;
                }
            }

            setTimeout(function () {
                // configure an event listener and remove the "onclick" property from the <input /> element
                document.getElementById("popupbtn").addEventlistener('click', function(){
                    var pageStatus = getPageStatus();
                    if (pageStatus=='initial') {
                        // once this has been done once, the click will no longer redirect
                        setPageStatus('loaded');
                        location.href = '/api'
                    } else {
                        alert('The button has been used.');
                    }
                });
            }, 500);

        </script>
```

Be sure to read up on [Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Beware that you have to manually control this so that if you want the button to work on a future visit to the page, you will need to reset the stored value. The above method will kill the button click until the user clears their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you appear to be reloading the page in the onClick event (which I'd highly recommend changing to just loading in a hidden div which would allow you to use a global or other document based mechanism), you'll have to use a query string option.

Something like this:

```
<input onclick="location.href = '/api?fromclick=yes';" type="hidden" id="popupbtn">
<script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('fromclick') == -1) {
       setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("popupbtn").click();}, 500);
    }
</script>
```